# Popup filter with OpenLayers3

Tags: javascript, openlayers

When I load my map, I load my vector overlay with this code :

```
var vector_overlay1 = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({
        url: 'json.json',
        defaultProjection :'EPSG:4326',
        projection: 'EPSG:3857'
    }), 
    name: 'NAME 1',
    style:  function(feature, resolution){
        ...
    }
});
```

And

```
map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [BASE LAYER,vector_overlay1,vector_overlay2]
});
```

After, I added a DIV to my map with a list of **names** object of my **vector_overlay** associate with a **search button**.

When a user select a value in my list, the map **zoom** on the object of the list and a **popup** appear with the informations of this object.

That is my problem, because the popup make an interrogation of all the vector layers. I try to make a filter like that :

```
var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(map.getPixelFromCoordinate(destination_center),
    function(feature, layer){
        return feature;
    }, null, function(layer){
        return layer.get('name') === 'NAME 1';
    }
);
```

But it's not the solution, and if I try :

function(layer){
    return layer === vector_overlay1;
});

Firebug say : **vector_overlay1 is not defined**
So I've two questions :

**1)** Where can I choose if I want to my overlay is selectable ?

**2)** How can I add a layerfilter with an overlay define at the load map ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you are using the latest Openlayers version -- 3.5.0, you have to adapt your code to the [new changes](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/releases/tag/v3.5.0).

Specifically:

```
var source = new ol.source.GeoJSON({
  url: 'features.json',
  projection: 'EPSG:3857'
});
```

To:

```
var source = new ol.source.Vector({
  url: 'features.json',
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
});
```

The "selectable part" you can do something like this ([online](http://plnkr.co/edit/hhEAWk?p=preview)):

```
map.on('click', function(evt) {
    var f = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(
        evt.pixel,
        function(ft, layer){return ft;}
    );
    if (f && f.get('type') == 'click') {
        var geometry = f.getGeometry();
        var coord = geometry.getCoordinates();

        var content = '<p>'+f.get('desc')+'</p>';

        popup.show(coord, content);

    } else { popup.hide(); }

});
map.on('pointermove', function(e) {
    if (e.dragging) { popup.hide(); return; }

    var pixel = map.getEventPixel(e.originalEvent);
    var hit = map.hasFeatureAtPixel(pixel);

    map.getTarget().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
});
```

Comment: Okay Jonathan, thank you, I understand your response but in my case, if I add the property "type" to my overlay, I can't take it when I do : "f.get()" because I'm in the second level of the properties, the level of my GeoJson data's.

Comment: I find a solution : `map.on('click', function(evt) {var recup_layer = map.forEachLayerAtPixel(
   evt.pixel,
   function(ft, layer){return ft;}
  );
  var recup_prop = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(
   evt.pixel,
   function(ft, layer){return ft;}
  );
  
  if (recup_layer && recup_layer.get('name') == 'Poteaux TAD') {
   
   var geometry = recup_prop.getGeometry();
   var coord = geometry.getCoordinates();
   
   var content = '<p>'+recup_prop.get('nom')+'</p>';
   
   popup.show(coord, content);
   
  } else { popup.hide(); }
  
 });`

Comment: Glad to know you got it.